# How to keep playing video while changing to landscape Mode android (resume video)

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm playing video using `VideoView` in portrait mode (not on full screen). When I change to landscape mode, the video not resume (like youtube). Any Suggestion? Here is my code.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Checks the orientation of the screen

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_office_detail);

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BoxOfficeDetailActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Video now loading ...", true);

        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }).start();

        videoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tvVideo);
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSynopsis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSynopsis);
        tvCast = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCast);

        BoxOfficeMovie movie = (BoxOfficeMovie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(BoxOfficeActivity.MOVIE_DETAIL_KEY);
        loadMovie(movie);
    }

    public void loadMovie(BoxOfficeMovie movie) {
         videoView.setVideoPath(movie.getVideo());
         MediaController mediaController = new
         MediaController(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
         videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
         videoView.start();
         videoView.requestFocus();
         tvTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
         tvCast.setText(movie.getCastList() + " views");
         tvSynopsis.setText(movie.getSynopsis());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid activity destruction, by adding this for the activity in the manifest `android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenSize"`

Answer (score 0):

Well odds are that on Orientation change you will need to destroy your video view and then reinstate it after the orientation change and resume playback from where it was left off at.

A little side note, I have had nothing but problems working with VideoView and MediaPlayer in Android development. Especially getting those 2 things to work correctly across multiple devices. If I were you, I would look into the ExoPlayer library to support video playback. But I guess that depends on how big of a part of your app video playback will be. ExoPlayer takes a significant more amount of time to get setup and working correctly however it still isnt hard and the performance and stability improvement make it work it.